# span causes content inside to be lower?

Tags: css

I'm adding a span to wrap a certain part of text so that I can apply a specific font to it, but for some reason it drops below so that part of it is under the baseline of the paragraph that contains all the text.

Anyone have any ideas on how to move it ( the span ) up so that it is on the same line as the rest of the text?

I'm trying relative positioning, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Here is the code:

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
        html, body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        font-size:16px;
        }
        .container{
        height:342px;
        width:100%;
        padding-top:2em;
        padding-left:2em;
        background:#ffffff;
        background:rgb(255, 255, 255);
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
       box-sizing:border-box;
       color:#333333;
       color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
       font-family:'Trend';
       font-size:120%;
       font-size:1.2rem;
       *behavior:url(../scripts/boxsizing.htc);
    }
    #welcome{
        background:#8cc047;
        background:rgb(140, 192, 71);
    }
    #welcome p.title{
        margin:0;
        font-size:225%;
        font-size:2.25rem;
    }
    #name{
        position:relative;
        font-family:'Cubano-web',Cubano,'Trend';
        left:16px;
        top:-7.1px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="container" id="welcome">
        <p class="title">Hello,</p>
        <p class="title">I'm <span id="name">Noah</span>&mdash;</p>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello in First line and other text in another line if this is what you need
then 
add this css to title class

```
.title{
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
  }
```

and remove the  top and left property from `#name`
making it like this..

remove the `position:relative` also;

```
 #name{
            font-family:'Cubano-web',Cubano,'Trend';
    }
```

here is the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/tFJ2x/1/

Comment: LOL what makes my example different than this?

Comment: You are using position:relative and he wanted some other way. Nevermind if your answer dosen't satisfies this OP it will certainly be helpful for others. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the question but if you want it on the same line you shouldn't be splitting the text into 2 `<p>` tags

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/HfvKA/)

```
<header class="container" id="welcome">
    <p class="title">Hello, I'm <span id="name">Noah</span>&mdash;</p>
</header>
```

### Edit

OK, so I think you're using custom fonts which hardly anyone will be using and that's what is sparking this question. I recommend you either the [standard fonts for Mac and Windows](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html) or CSS3 [`@font-face`](http://www.font-face.com/) to include different fonts otherwise you can't be sure the user will have them (like now).

As for aligning a custom font, basically you can't really do this nicely and guarantee that it will show up correctly. You can try for example with `position:relative;` like you were using in which case I recommend using `em` not `px`. Using `em` will get around lots of responsive issues from zooming and different devices because you will be moving it based on the size of the font and not pixels.

Comment: The Hello, is supposed to be on one line and the I'm Noah is supposed to be on another. But all of the text in the I'm Noah line is supposed to be in one line, the word Noah is pushed down.

Comment: Updated after I understand now.

Comment: I am using @font-face to include the custom fonts.

Comment: Well then yea, the best way to align them is to do it as you were doing (relative positioning or margin) and hope it appears like that on most devices.

Comment: Ah, okay. I guess that is what I'll do then.